# Rounding off the Float to highest

Tags: android, kotlin, rounding

I am using below code to round off the float result to an integer.

```
230.div(20.00).toFloat().roundToInt())
```

The above example gives me 11.5 roundng off to Int 12 but the same code is not rounding of 5.3 to 6

```
106.div(20.00).toFloat().roundToInt())
```

Is there any way to round off the float to highest i.e 5.3 to 6

Comment: isn't that working like it should ? rounding up if over 4, rounding down if under ? sounds like you essentially want to round up, not round off ?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/ceil.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chosen answer is Java Math.ceil,

here it is in Kotlin (for floats)

```
import kotlin.math.ceil

val finalValue : Int = ceil(5.3f).toInt()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Math.ceil(5.3)` to round it to 6. It will return `Double` then you can use `toInt()` on it. Like this:

```
val value = 106.div(20.00)
val finalValue = Math.ceil(value).toInt()
```

Comment: is there any point to using `roundToInt()` at that point ? probably just converting to int would be enough, would you even have decimal values at that point still ?

Comment: You are right, even there won't be any decimal points but the datatype would still be Double. If he wants to convert it to Integer then he can use roundToInt() otherwise it can be skipped :) And converting to Int is not enough because he wants to convert if value is 5.3 then it should be 6. roundToInt() would convert it to closest round value which is 5 :)

Comment: using your  5.3 as example, then `Math.ceil(value)` will already give you something like 6.0, won't it ? so what is the scenario where `roundToInt()` is going to be useful ?

Comment: In current scenario, it would give you 6.0 then roundToInt() will convert it to 6

Comment: so how is that different than calling toInt ? int values don't have decimals, it will just be getting rid of the .0

Comment: Yes definitely, edited my answer :) Thanks for pointing it out.